# UITableView Autolayout Positioning

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

Working in ios8/xcode6/swift

I have a UITableView that will generally have 2-3 items in it. As a result, it does not need to be very large. Although I could just use my own labels or not even a datasourced control at all, I kind of like how UITableView encapsulates everything for me, as well as the nifty lines it has between each item.

That being said, the behavior should be that the number of lines on the screen between each UITableViewCell equals the # of items bound to its datasource, correct?

So if I have 2 items, I should only see 2 rows.

Not sure if this is autolayout-related but when I view my table, the height is such that several extra blank rows get created (like 8 in total). So there are 8 clickable blank rows, when there should only be 2.

I did try removing constraints (once I ever just said use leading margin) so I could align it left, but no matter what I do (or don't do) there seems to be more rows than what I need.

Would you advise dynamically setting the height based on the # of items? I thought it was supposed to do this automatically ..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up doing it:

```
myTableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

it works great now! Had nothing to do with autolayout I suspect.